# Return something if row doesn't exist with Prepared Statement Query

Tags: mysql

I'm using a simple query to return the content of several rows :

```
 SELECT a, b FROM TABLE WHERE id IN(?,?,?)
```

I'm trying to echo that a row / id doesn't exist if that's the case

I read here about `ifnull` but I can't figure out how to properly use it with my query which is using `IN`.

Any suggestion ? Thanks a lot

Comment: What about accessing the [`num_rows`](http://php.net/mysqli_num_rows) property from your result set object?

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement doesn't make lot of sense to me but you can use below query to achieve it -

```
SELECT IFNULL((SELECT 1 from TABLE WHERE id IN (?,?,?) ), 'No Records Found');
```